# Error while installing Flutter (probably Java)

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart

Full disclaimer, I am new to this stuff.
While running `flutter doctor --android-licenses`, I get the following error:-

`Error: Could not find or load main class Krishna\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmdline-tools\latest\bin\\.. Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Krishna\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmdline-tools\latest\bin\\//`

I look forward to any solutions! Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your Sdk path looks fishy `latest\bin\\//` something is very wrong here. Fix that first in your environment variables. It should look like something ending with `latest\bin\`

```
Krishna\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmdline-tools\latest\bin\
```

Comment: Actually there is no such environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

I got this same problem when I installed flutter again

Open Android Studio and go to SDK Manager and click SDK Tools

And download tools shown in this picture

[SDK Tools for Android Licenses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBhhC.jpg)

Restart your pc and run 'flutter run-v' in cmd or terminal

Comment: If it Still doesn't work Please Let me Know !!